# Facing NULL Pointer Exception In Java Aggregation

Tags: java

While learning aggregation in Java, I have come across **NULLPointerException** , Please help me identifying the root cause.
There are 3 classes.

1. Student
2. Department.
3. Institution.

   package com.java.inheritance;
       import java.util.List;
       import java.io.*;

   ```
   public class Department {

       private String name;
       private List<Student> listofstudents;

       Department(String name,List<Student> listofstudents){

           this.name =name;
           this.listofstudents = listofstudents;
       }

       public List<Student> getStudents(){

           return this.listofstudents;
       }


   }
   ```

package com.java.inheritance;

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int id;
    private String Department;

    Student(String name,int id,String Department){

        this.name =name;
        this.id= id;
        this.Department = Department;

    }

}



    package com.java.inheritance;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Institute {

       private String institureName;
       private List<Department> listofDept;

      public Institute(String institureName,List<Department> listofDept){
           this.institureName = institureName;
           this.listofDept = listofDept;
       }

      public List<Department> getDepartments(){
          return this.listofDept;
      }

      // Get total number of Student in a Institute.

      public int gettotalnoofStudents(){
          int numberofStudent = 0;
          List<Student> listofStudent=null;
          for (Department dept:listofDept){
              listofStudent = dept.getStudents();
              for (Student student:listofStudent){

                  numberofStudent++;  
              }

          }

          return numberofStudent;
      }


    } // End of Institute
```

Now I am calling them in another class, MainClass.

```
package com.java.inheritance;
import java.util.List;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{  
        List<Student> sciencestudents=null;
        List<Student> artstudnets=null;
        Student s1= new Student("Asfakul",1,"Science");
        Student s2=new Student("Arizul",2,"Science");
        Student s3=new Student("Noor",3,"Arts");

        sciencestudents.add(s1);
        sciencestudents.add(s2);
        artstudnets.add(s3);


        Department d1=new Department("Science",sciencestudents);
        Department d2=new Department("Arts",artstudnets);

        List<Department> departmentlist=null;
        departmentlist.add(d1);
        departmentlist.add(d2);

        Institute i1= new Institute("BEC",departmentlist);
        System.out.println(i1.gettotalnoofStudents());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting **NULLpointerException** at this point. Where have I done wrong.

Comment: Your `sciencestudents` List is `null`. Create a new list first before you try adding something to it.

Comment: "at this point" Where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your lists before you add to them.

```
    List<Student> sciencestudents=null;
    List<Student> artstudnets=null;
    Student s1= new Student("Asfakul",1,"Science");
    Student s2=new Student("Arizul",2,"Science");
    Student s3=new Student("Noor",3,"Arts");

    sciencestudents.add(s1);
    sciencestudents.add(s2);
    artstudnets.add(s3);
```

Here you're adding to a null list, which causes the exception. Try creating a new `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

```
List<Student> sciencestudents = new ArrayList<>();
List<Student> artstudents = new ArrayList<>();
```

And similarly, you'll need to create a department list as well.

```
List<Department> departmentlist = new ArrayList<>();
```